# Filter dynamic e-commerce in PHP

Tags: php, sql, filtering, e-commerce

Post table is products list, post_feature is the features of the products,

The image of the posts table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwXxz.jpg)

The image of the posts features:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEufj.jpg)

The issue: If I choose the id 1 and 3 features, It should list the product only id 5. But the SQL command at the bottom lists the products id 8.

```
SELECT * FROM post_feature INNER JOIN posts ON 
post_feature.pfeature_postid=posts.post_id WHERE
post_feature.pfeature_featureid IN (implode(",",$ozellikler))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM post_feature INNER JOIN posts ON  post_feature.pfeature_postid=posts.post_id WHERE find_in_set(post_feature.pfeature_featureid, ' . $implode(",", $ozellikler) . ')';`

Comment: Can you explain your query, what is it doing.

Comment: $post=DB::Connect()->query('SELECT * FROM post_feature INNER JOIN posts ON  post_feature.pfeature_postid=posts.post_id WHERE FIND_IN_SET(post_feature.pfeature_featureid, ' . implode(",", $FilterValue) . ')')->fetchAll();
 ERROR :SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET' in

Comment: Hi Ahmet, you can read on this about find_in_set https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php